# print(hybrid[22,'to',88,34,'test']) TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python

```py
def hybrid(letnum):
    return [num for num in letnum if isinstance(num,int)]

print(hybrid[22,'to',88,34,'test'])
```

please someone should help me point out the error in the above python code. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are calling function `hybrid` without parentheses.

Fix:

```py
def hybrid(letnum):
    return [num for num in letnum if isinstance(num,int)]

print(hybrid([22,'to',88,34,'test']))
```

Comment: Hello 'Filio Hanes' thanks so much for you answer, it fix it. really appreciate